# Mongo stuck on save

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

We have a single node of Mongo holding data in a single collection. We run it on windows 2008 64-bit machine with 128 GB RAM.
The size of the collection is ~2TB holding ~200M items.
Lately, when we save new data to this collection, the save operation take lots of time and after a while get stuck.
When it happens, we restart the mongod service and it cause the application to work for couple of minutes, but then it get stuck again.

I don't see any locks in the dashboard, but I see operations which are "active" and "waiting" (they are actually stuck)
There are also read operations (~100 qps) which we have on this collection.

Is there a limitation on Mongo size on windows?
Any other suggestions what's wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here is some information gathered from MMS, showing a state in which all 164 writers are stuck waiting for the global Q, they are stuck for days now.

[image]

Comment: Is this a coding question? Are you possibly running a 32-bit instance of MongoDB?

Comment: The max sixe of 32bit is 2GB as such 2TB would not be 32bit, no, this is something else. We need more information, version, iostat, mongotop maybe. If you have this connected to MMS can you send us the stat graphs? Though this question might get migrated at that point to dba

Comment: It is 64 bit, we're not using MMS. I'll get some more info the next time it will get stuck. Thanks

Comment: If your working set is bigger than memory, most of your operations will be IO bound. Did you consider sharding?

Comment: Yes, in the long run I know we should do sharding. The working set is  small. Plus the save is not just slower as you would expect in IO bound operations, it just gets stuck forever.

Comment: In-depth administrations questions like this are much more appropriate on dba.stackexchange.com, but before you post the question there you should add the information Sammaye is asking for.